# What's the median of $f(x) = 4xe^{-2x}$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, median

I'm trying to find the median of $f(x) = 4xe^{-2x}$.

So far, I've tried solving for $q_{50}$ by plugging it into an integral and setting it equal to 0.5 like so: $\int_{0}^{q_{50}} 4xe^{-2x} dx = 0.5$. I eventually get to $-2q_{50}e^{-2q_{50}} - e^{-2q_{50}} + 1 = 0.5$. Unfortunately, at this point, I have been unable to solve for $q_{50}$.

Is there something I've done wrong up to this point or another method that I could be using instead to find the median? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks right to me.  Solving it numerically, as [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+-2x*exp%28-2x%29-exp%28-2x%29%3D-.5) yields $q_{50}\approx .839173$

Comment: here it is in [DESMOS](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xsvkhq06zq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation
\begin{align}
-2q_{50}e^{-2q_{50}} - e^{-2q_{50}} + 1 = 0.5
\end{align}
i.e.
\begin{align}
(2q_{50}+1)e^{-2q_{50}}= 0.5
\end{align}
is correct, however it is trascendental and must be solved numerically. Using MAPLE for example you can find $q_{50}\approx 0.839173495$.

Comment: Perfect! I'll have to do some more research as to what transcendental means and what numerical solving is but, this is very helpful and a good starting point. Thank you!

Comment: Not at all. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation

Answer (score 2):

Letting $x=q_{50}$, as @Vítězslav Štembera answered, you want to solve for $x$ the equation
$$ (2 x+1)\,e^{-2 x}=k \quad\implies\quad(2x+1)\,e^{-(2 x+1)}=\frac k e$$ The only explicit solution of it is given by
$$x=-\frac{1}{2} \left(1+W_{-1}\left(-\frac{k}{e}\right)\right)$$ where $W_{-1}(.)$ is the second branch of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

If you cannot use Lambert function, only numerical methods would give the solution.